# Nodejs script doesn't print characters like 'ò' on the windows terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, character-encoding

I have a Nodejs script that reads a file, and than prints a paragraph on the console.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var math = require('mathjs');

var piece = "";
var path = "./divina_commedia.txt";
var stats = fs.statSync(path);
var start = math.round(math.random(stats.size));
var opt = { flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf8', autoclose: true, start: start, end: start + 2000 };
var input = fs.createReadStream(path, opt);
input.on('end', () => { clean() })
input.on('data', store);

function store(chunk) {
    piece = piece + chunk;
}

function clean() {
    var subs = piece.match(/[A-Z][^\.]*\./g);
    console.log(subs[0] + subs[1]);
}

console.log("ò"); // <<-- this is printed on the terminal
```

The accented characters are not printed on the terminal. By the way it's possible to print on the terminal accented characters, the last line of my script proves it.

Comment: Can you provide your text file, since it's perfectly working for me.

Comment: the file is the following: https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG_7O33t3KAhVF1ywKHWCNCVAQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoepliscuola.it%2Fdownload%2F2842%2Fla-divina-commedia-txt.aspx&usg=AFQjCNG9GLc-QsAyIzTKX0UluZjlrGEw1Q&sig2=DTzeFHszNSHSULrvT0RdCQ&bvm=bv.113370389,d.bGg

Comment: Thanks for help, but I've found a solution setting the enconding to 'binary'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your [file](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG_7O33t3KAhVF1ywKHWCNCVAQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoepliscuola.it%2Fdownload%2F2842%2Fla-divina-commedia-txt.aspx&usg=AFQjCNG9GLc-QsAyIzTKX0UluZjlrGEw1Q&sig2=DTzeFHszNSHSULrvT0RdCQ&bvm=bv.113370389,d.bGg) isn't in `utf8`, is a `windows-1252` encoded file.

[image]

Use [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) to decode it.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var math = require('mathjs');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var piece = "";
var path = "./divina_commedia.txt";

var opt = {
    flags: 'r',
    autoclose: true,
    start: start,
    end: start + 2000
    //remove utf8
};

var input = fs.createReadStream(path, opt)
              .pipe(iconv.decodeStream('win1252')); //decode

input.on('end', clean);
input.on('data', store);

function store(chunk) {
    piece = piece + chunk;
}

function clean() {
    piece = piece.toString(); //Buffer to string
    var subs = piece.match(/[A-Z][^\.]*\./g);
    console.log(piece); //ò printed correctly
}
```

Or you can just convert the file to utf8 beforehand and use your code.